# generate random password [C++]

Tags: c++

i'm learning c++ and i've been trying to create a 'generator passwords' and i have few problems:
here is source (int main):

```
//Declaring Variables
int PasswordNumbers, PasswordChar;
char alphabet[26] = { 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z' };
string * passwords;
string password;

//Message and Input
cout << "How Many Passwords Should Generate ?" << endl;
cin >> PasswordNumbers;

cout << "How Many Letters/Numbers Should be in each Passowrd ?" << endl;
cin >> PasswordChar;

passwords = new string[PasswordNumbers];

for (int j = 0; j < PasswordNumbers; j++) { //How Many Passwords?
    for (int i = 0; i < PasswordChar; i++) { //How Many Letters/Numbers?
        int randomBool = rand() % 2;
        if (randomBool == 1) {
            int random = rand() % 10;
            password.append(to_string(random));
        }
        else {
            int random = rand() % 26;
            string randomLetter = to_string(alphabet[random]);
            password.append(randomLetter);
        }
    }
    passwords[j] = password;
}

for (int i = 0; i < passwords->length(); i++) {
    printf("Random Number: %s \n", passwords[i].c_str());
}

delete[] passwords;
```

[image: cmd]

Problems:

1. Generating only numbers.
2. not generating the amount of letters/numbers the user has chosen.
3. Generating same numbers.

the code looks fine to me, i cant see something wrong ...

Comment: The best tool to use for this is your debugger.

Comment: I think when you pass a `char` to `to_string` it doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Use srand() to seed the random numbers, if you do not do this, it will in each execution show same numbers. Look into pseudo-random numbers.

Comment: You're not clearing `password` between each iteration of the outer loop, so you just keep appending to the previous password.

Comment: put the MakePassword logic in a separate function, it will makes things clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting only numbers because there's no specialization of `std::to_string()` for `char`. So when you do `to_string(alphabet[random]))`, it converts the `char` to `int` (which returns the letter's character code) and then converts that to a string. So `to_string('a')` is `"97"`, not `"a"`.

Instead of an array, you could use a string containing the alphabet. `std::string::append()` allows you to specify a substring to copy from. So you can do:

```
string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
int random = rand() % alphabet.size();
password.append(alphabet, random, 1);
```

This also explains why your password isn't the desired length. When it intends to append a character, it's instead appending 2 or 3 digit numbers.

Finally, you're not clearing `password` each time you want to generate a new password, so you're appending to the old password. The simple solution to this is to move the `string password;` declaration inside the first `for` loop.

You should also call `srand(time())` at the beginning of your program, so you'll get different passwords every time you run it. Otherwise the program always starts with the same random seed.